# Copy Name File and Rename Another File with that Name

Tags: batch-rename

I don't know anything about code or even to use CMD, but I would like to know how to rename a file with another's file name. Example:

I have a movie:

```
MOVIE.720p.2017.mkv
```

and a have a subtitle with the correct name

```
MOVIE 720p (2017).srt
```

what I want to do is copy the name from the .srt to the .mkv, without copying the extension.

but, I have a lot of movies with a lot of .srt, the command needs to know a rule to know which movies are which.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TOTALCMD, very easy. Select the file and press `Ctr+R` (this task is make without copying the extension)

Just configure in TotalCmd this combination of task Ctr+R. `Menu -> Configuration -> Misc -> Ctr + Win + R (from combobox) + Command (Select RenameOnly)`. Press APPLY

[image]